# Spyder Console: Autocompletion duplicates code while defining a new variable

Tags: python, autocomplete, ipython, spyder, dot-notation

I recently experience an annoying bug with TAB autocompletion in the Spyder IPython console: when I define a new variable that is dependent on a property called with dot notation, autocompleting the property duplicates all previous code from the current line.

This gets quite annoying when I want to autocomplete more complicated variable definitions and goes completely against the point of autocompletion, i.e., to speed things up.

**Here a simple example**

*Goal*: define an array containing the first nine multiples of 3 with numpy.arange like this

```
import numpy as np
x = 3 * np.arange(1,10,1)
```

*Expectation*: Pressing TAB while writing np.arange (e.g., "np.ara"+TAB) should autocomplete the arange function name.
However, this happens instead:

```
import numpy as np
x = 3 * x = 3 * np.arange
```

*Already tried*: update Anaconda, update Spyder